# md-selected with ng-repeat on md-tab

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-material

I've a problem, I've searched before asking question but anything helped me so far.
I am using md-tabs of angular-materials with Angular 1.x, it works fine, but I would like to make tab bookmarkable so I would like to use md-selected attribute on md-tabs mark.
However, I tried several things, nothing seems to work with it.

Here my HTML code :

```
<md-content>
    <md-tabs
        md-no-ink-bar
        md-no-ink
        md-dynamic-height=""
        md-border-bottom=""
        md-selected="selectedIndex.index"
    >
        <md-tab
            ng-disabled="true"
            id="my_id"
        >
            <i class="fa fa-dashboard"></i> Non clickable tab
        </md-tab>
        <md-tab
            ng-repeat="tab in tabs"
            label="my_label"
        >
            <my-directive
                tab-id="tab.id"
                ng-if="tab.id == tabActiveId"
            ></my-directive>
        </md-tab>
    </md-tabs>
</md-content>
```

And I set a variable (hard-coded for tests) in my controller :

```
$scope.selectedIndex = {
    index: 2
  };
```

Unfortunately it does not works at all.

Any idea ?

Thanks by advance

Comment: Didn't get the question. Can you explain this with an example ?

Comment: Of course, for being simple, when I set `<md-tabs md-selected="2">...</md-tabs>` it does not select my second tab at loading (nor after). I assume it might be a ng-repeat side-effet because on loading md-tabs each md-tab is not created yet (due to the ng-repeat)

Comment: there is an example on the [angular-material-website](https://material.angularjs.org/latest/demo/tabs) for this exact setup

Comment: I know and I've followed this example but it still not working for me

Comment: Problem solved, the issue came from the disable tab in first